# Image file not being uploaded/created using multer

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am building a blog site, everything is working fine except the `image upload` on my `Post`.
The `post` works 100% but when i attach `image` it does not get `uploaded or created`, i don't know what i am doing wrong, please i need a help. I started learning `node` and `express` few months ago. Please help me.

inside index.js file

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
```

My schema

```
const BlogPost = new Schema({
 author: ObjectId,
 title: String,
 body: String,
 profileimage: String,
 date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
 comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', BlogPost);



router.post("/makepost", upload.single('profileimage'), (req, res) => {

 var myData = new Post(req.body);
 if(req.file) {
   console.log('Uploading File....');
   var profileimage = req.file.filename;
   console.log(profileimage)
 }else {
   console.log('No File Uploaded....');
  var profileimage = 'noimage.jpg';
 }
 myData.save()
 .then(item => {
 res.redirect('/posts');
})
.catch(err => {
 res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
});
});
```

and here is my view

```
<form action='/makepost' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <p>Title: <input type='text' name='title' </p>
 <p>Content: <input type='text' name='body' </p>
 <div class="form-group"> <label>Profile Image</label><input class="form-control" 
   name="profileimage" type="file" />
 <p><input type='submit' value='post'></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using multer with disk-storage, you need to read the image from the temporary location before storing it with mongoose. Besides I would change the image datatype in the mongoose schema to `buffer`.

Something like this should work (note that I'm using async/await instead of promises directly):

```
router.post("/makepost", upload.single('profileimage'), async (req, res) => {

    const newPost = new Post(req.body);
    if (req.file) {         
        const imgBuffer = await fs.promises.readFile(req.file.path); // TODO add error handling
        newPost.profileimage = imgBuffer;
    }
    try {
        await myData.save();
        res.redirect('/posts');
    }catch(err) {
        res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    }
});

// mongoose schema
...
profileimage: Buffer,
...
```

You could also store the image as a Base64-encoded string and keep the datatype `string` in the schema.

**EDIT:**

As discussed in the comments - change the datatype of profileimage back to `string` as profileimage will just contain the path to the file.

```
router.post("/makepost", upload.single('profileimage'), async (req, res) => {

    const newPost = new Post(req.body);
    if (req.file) {         
        newPost.profileimage = req.file.path;
    }
    ...
```

Add an express middleware to serve the images, e.g.

```
app.use(express.static('./uploads'));
```

Comment: @Chukwuma Kingsley: Or are you just trying to save the path to the image in mongodb and keep the images in the file system?

Comment: the code you gave me worked, thank you so much. However, it can't display on the browser, and the image url that was generated is too long and looks like a binary code. do you perhaps know why it 's so? Sorry i'm new to Node and express,  i am coming from Rails.  Here is my view  `<img src="<%= item.profileimage %>" alt="image">`

Comment: You can serve the image using express and probably it would be easier to just save the file location in mongodb and serve it from the file system. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: it's now getting saved in the DB, and in *uploads*  folder. my challenge now is how to display it on the screen, when i try to display it on the screen i get `404` on my console meaning that the image is not found. i try to send it through json after upload and this is what get shown `{"file":{"fieldname":"profileimage","originalname":"church.jpg","encoding":"7bit","mimetype":"image/jpeg","destination":"./uploads","filename":"658f572f5b848b0444e2b59c7d7c2880","path":"uploads/658f572f5b848b0444e2b59c7d7c2880","size":52651}}`       
 Here is my view `src="./uploads/<%= item.profileimage %>`

Comment: Did you add the middleware to serve static content? I've created a simple example that should help you: https://pastebin.com/wNS4kCVt

Comment: Thank you so much. your answer pointed me at the right direction and my image was getting saved except that i could not display the image because of location problem.  I decided to watch some Tutorials on Youtube on how to use multer to upload image. after watching two different tutorial i was able to get the location set properly. i really appreciate the time you took to help me, the link you gave me to look though  really helped me a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: Just did that.  Sorry I was supposed to do that long ago but I forgot